# Elasticsearch: analyzer on nested elements

Tags: elasticsearch, postfix-mta

Hi i am using this template for postfix :

```
PUT /_template/postfix
{
  "template": "postfix*",
  "settings":{
     "index":{
        "analysis":{
           "analyzer":{
              "email":{
                 "tokenizer":"keyword",
                 "filter":"lowercase"
              }
           }
        }
     }
  },
  "mappings": {
    "logs": {
      "properties": {
        "@timestamp": {
          "type": "date",
          "format": "strict_date_optional_time||epoch_millis"
        },
        "@version": {
          "type": "string"
        },
        "clienthostname": {
          "type": "string"
        },
        "clientip": {
          "type": "ip"
        },
        "delay": {
          "type": "double"
        },
        "deferred": {
          "type": "boolean"
        },
        "delays": {
          "type": "string"
        },
        "dsn": {
          "type": "string"
        },
        "entry_date": {
          "type": "string"
        },
        "lastqueueid": {
          "type": "string"
        },
        "logsource": {
          "type": "string"
        },
        "mailfrom": {
          "type": "string",
          "index": "not_analyzed"
        },
        "mailsize": {
          "type": "long"
        },
        "numberofrecipients": {
          "type": "long"
        },
        "pid": {
          "type": "long"
        },
        "postfixdaemon": {
          "type": "string"
        },
        "program": {
          "type": "string"
        },
        "queueid": {
          "type": "string"
        },
        "recipients": {
          "type" : "nested",
          "properties": {
            "rcptto": {"type": "string", "analyzer":"email" }
          }
        },
        "relay": {
          "type": "string"
        },
        "relayip": {
          "type": "string"
        },
        "removal_time": {
          "type": "string"
        },
        "removed": {
          "type": "string"
        },
        "status": {
          "type": "string"
        },
        "tags": {
          "type": "string"
        },
        "timestamp": {
          "type": "string"
        },
        "total_delay": {
          "type": "long"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

My recipients field is nested, and i am using an analyzer to do the job (keep a full mail address and convert to lowercase). When i am testing the analyzer with this request it's doing the job well :

```
GET /_analyze
{
    "tokenizer":"uax_url_email",
    "filters":["lowercase"],
    "text":["test","misterABCD@customer.fr"]

}
```

It returns :

```
{
   "tokens": [
      {
         "token": "test",
         "start_offset": 0,
         "end_offset": 4,
         "type": "<ALPHANUM>",
         "position": 0
      },
      {
         "token": "misterabcd@customer.fr",
         "start_offset": 5,
         "end_offset": 27,
         "type": "<EMAIL>",
         "position": 1
      }
   ]
}
```

But when i am indexing my data, the recipients.rcpto field is not converted lowercase, and when i do a search request on recipients.rcptto it doesn't work.
It looks like my rcptto part is not indexed correctly.

indexing data :

```
POST /postfix/logs
{
                 "status" : "sent",
                "queueid" : "3nTgBP6Mrpz18dwD",
          "postfixdaemon" : "smtpd",
             "recipients" : [
             {
                 "rcptto" : "misterABCD@customer.fr"
             },
             {
                 "rcptto" : "misterDEfG@test.com"
             }
         ],
               "mailfrom" : "misterB@something.fr",
               "clientip" : "127.0.0.1",
         "clienthostname" : "server.fr",
                    "pid" : 7996,
                 "delays" : "0.06/0/0/0.28",
              "logsource" : "smtp2",
            "total_delay" : 1,
               "mailsize" : 23792,
                  "delay" : 0.34,
                "program" : "postfix",
             "entry_date" : "Jan  5 00:45:33",
              "timestamp" : "Jan  5 00:45:33",
                "removed" : "True",
               "@version" : "1",
             "@timestamp" : "2016-01-04T23:45:33.000Z"
 }
```

Request based on "status" field :

```
GET /postfix*/_search
{
  "fields":"recipients.rcptto",
  "query": {
    "term": {
      "status": "sent"
    }
  }
}
```

Return :

```
{
   "took": 2,
   "timed_out": false,
   "_shards": {
      "total": 5,
      "successful": 5,
      "failed": 0
   },
   "hits": {
      "total": 1,
      "max_score": 0.30685282,
      "hits": [
         {
            "_index": "postfix",
            "_type": "logs",
            "_id": "AVP00rA5U5V4nhi9E0IJ",
            "_score": 0.30685282,
            "fields": {
               "recipients.rcptto": [
                  "misterABCD@customer.fr",
                  "misterDEfG@test.com"
               ]
            }
         }
      ]
   }
}
```

Request based on "recipients.rcptto" field (Updated with Richa reply) :

```
{
"query": {
  "nested": {
     "path": "recipients",
     "query": {
        "match": {
           "recipients.rcptto": "misterabcd@customer.fr"
           }
       }
     }
   }
}
```

Return:

```
   {
   "took": 6,
   "timed_out": false,
   "_shards": {
      "total": 5,
      "successful": 5,
      "failed": 0
   },
   "hits": {
      "total": 1,
      "max_score": 1.4054651,
      "hits": [
         {
            "_index": "postfix",
            "_type": "logs",
            "_id": "AVP1zqtwU5V4nhi9E0Ih",
            "_score": 1.4054651,
            "_source": {
               "status": "sent",
               "queueid": "3nTgBP6Mrpz18dwD",
               "postfixdaemon": "smtpd",
               "recipients": [
                  {
                     "rcptto": "misterABCD@customer.fr"
                  },
                  {
                     "rcptto": "misterDEfG@test.com"
                  }
               ],
               "mailfrom": "misterB@something.fr",
               "clientip": "127.0.0.1",
               "clienthostname": "server.fr",
               "pid": 7996,
               "delays": "0.06/0/0/0.28",
               "logsource": "smtp2",
               "total_delay": 1,
               "mailsize": 23792,
               "delay": 0.34,
               "program": "postfix",
               "entry_date": "Jan  5 00:45:33",
               "timestamp": "Jan  5 00:45:33",
               "removed": "True",
               "@version": "1",
               "@timestamp": "2016-01-04T23:45:33.000Z"
            }
         }
      ]
   }
}
```

The recipients are not converted lowercase, is it normal ?

Comment: Why do you feel that your field is not getting converted to lowercase? What query are you running??

Comment: Hi, thanks for your feedback i edited my post.

Answer (score 1):

Since your field is `nested` you need to use [Nested Query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/nested-query.html) in combination of [Match Query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-match-query.html). Don't use `Term Query` as it will look for exact match.

```
{
"query": {
  "nested": {
     "path": "recipients",
     "query": {
        "match": {
           "recipients.rcptto": "misterABCD@customer.fr"
           }
       }
     }
   }
}
```

Hope it helps...

Answer (score 0):

You have to distinguish original data and indexed data.

If you index email **misterABCD@customer.fr** you will have **misterABCD@customer.fr** in you source field and **misterabcd@customer.fr** in your index.

When you search email in ES it will return you result on **misterabcd@customer.fr**, because it is in index, but not for **misterABCD@customer.fr**

Comment: Thanks for your reply but this is not the problem, i updated initial to provide more details.

Comment: Elasticsearch keep source data in it's original form, without changing text case. Lowercase transformation happens only in index. After you search by this index it will return you original data. It is expected behaviour.